# log4net leave me a lot of .1 .2 .3 files

Tags: log4net

The log4net.config is like below.
I only want the log file to roll to a new file everyday. But it rolled so many times in one day, with the extension of `.1`, `.2`, `.3`...
I only log a few of the activities, so the log file should be small in file size. Usually I have no more than 100 lines of log in one day.

```xml
<appender name="DebugRollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <param name="File" value="D:\\log\\hdpca.bill.debug.log" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10240" />
  <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="100" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd&quot;.log&quot;" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    <param name="Header" value="&#13;&#10;----------------------header--------------------------&#13;&#10;" />
    <param name="Footer" value="&#13;&#10;----------------------footer--------------------------&#13;&#10;" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
    <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? Have you read the docs for rolling file appender?

Comment: If you are trying to roll this log by date why are you specifying a MaxFileSize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set appendToFile to **true**; otherwise you are going to be overwriting your log files.

There are also some issues with the other attributes you have specified.  If you wish to roll the log by date you need to remove MaxFileSize and you cannot specify MaxSizeRollBackups when rolling logs by date.  Give the config below a shot.  It should fix your issues.

So, In short:

1. appendToFile = true
2. Remove MaxFileSize
3. Remove MaxSizeRollBackups
4. Remove the ".log" from your File attribute and leave the one on DatePattern (this will make sure you get {date}.log and not .log{date}.log)

**Sample Configuration:**

```xml
<appender name="DebugRollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="D:\\log\\hdpca.bill.debug"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        <param name="Header" value="&#13;&#10;----------------------header--------------------------&#13;&#10;" />
        <param name="Footer" value="&#13;&#10;----------------------footer--------------------------&#13;&#10;" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
    </filter>
</appender>
```

Comment: I'm trying this. What's the \ in `<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />` for? I at first thought you mis-typed, but it turned out you were right.

Comment: The \ just escapes the g since g is a special character in datepattern.  It is the same as quoting the .log like so yyyyMMdd'.log'.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using the ´MaximumFileSize´ instead of the ´MaxFileSize´ property because it allows you to to use [suffixes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize.html): "KB", "MB" or "GB".

```
<maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
```

Your configuration sets the file size to 10KB (not much really).

**UPDATE:**
Maybe your datepattern is the problem. I am not sure if it is good to have escape sequences in there. Try this instead:

```
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
```

or even

```
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
```

Comment: I'll try that. But my .1 .2 files never reached 10KB.